# How to preinstall addin on Office Online server?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

Is there any way to preinstall an addin onto an on-premise Office Online server such that when a user starts Word online, the addin will already be there?

I've read the documentation on centralized deployment through Office 365, but it mentions Office Online server is not supported.